# create list using .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-lists

so basically i have this data:

```
const testMeasurments = [
  {
  data:[
  {name:"glucose",value:6,fill:'#57c0e8'},
  {name:"SpO2",value:5,fill:"#FF6565"},
  {name:"Blood Pressure",value:4,fill:"#FFDA83"},
  {name:"Body Weight",value:2,fill:"purple"}
  ]
}
]
```

what i want is to create an unordered list of values from this data. what i need is something like this:

```
<ul>
{testMeasurments.map(s=>
        <li>{s.data.value}</li>
)}
</ul>
```

to produce this:

```
        6
        5
        4
        2
```

Comment: And how have you tried to achieve this so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over both arrays to get to what you want to do.

```
<ul>
  { testMeasurments.map(
    s => s.data.map(
      m => <li>{m.value}</li>
    )
  )}
</ul>
```

[**See it live**](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-architecture-7zdnk)

Sometimes visualizing the data structure helps, I like to use Typescript to define the structure.

```
interface Measurement {
  data: MeasurementResult[]
}
interface MeasurementResult {
  name: string
  value: number
  fill: string
}
```

Here `testMeasurments` is of the same form as a `Measurement[]`. Meaning `testMeasurments` is an array of measurements. Each measurement has an array of "results". that is the inner array you are trying to get to :)